# For what is used composer.json

Tags: php, composer-php

I recently saw this "composer.json" in the major php frameworks, what is it? and what you can do with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`composer.json` Is just a config file that describes your application, and its *needs* !!

By that I mean, your application, its version, and what it **needs to work properly** (also known as the *dependency*) can all be written inside the `composer.json` file, to ease the burden of downloading or trying to use something without knowing what it needs it work in the first place.

For example, I could include a `composer.json` file for this [Image uploader](https://github.com/simon-eQ/BulletProof) repo, that says the repo **`requires`** the [the PHP GD](http://php.net/gd) library to work and submit the repo on [packagist](http://packagist.org/).

By doing that, whenever someone downloads the repo using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org), the required library (*its dependencies*) would also be downloaded along with it.

Check out the composer for this [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/composer.json) file. It gives you information about the author, the library and what it needs to work `require-dev:`, and where it is found `autoload:`.

Answer (score 3):

Composer is Dependency Manager for PHP . Composer will manage the dependancies you require on a project by project basis. This means that Composer will pull in all the required libraries, dependancies and manage them all in one place.

Answer (score 3):

Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to declare the dependent libraries your project needs and it will install them in your project for you.

[Full Details Here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)